# How to make sure that an element does not exceed of screen in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a probleme that I can not manage in swiftUI : I have some elements in a VStack, a view goes beyond the screen, is normal, but my menu exceed also, it's normal behavior but not the desired result. I don't know how to bypass this result.

The component that exceed:

[image]

The component menu that must not exceed:

[image]

Code of the contentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.clear)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(red: 189/255, green: 195/255, blue: 199/255, opacity: 1.0), .white]), startPoint: .topTrailing, endPoint: .bottomLeading), 
cornerRadius: 0)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      VStack() {
        ScreenTitle()
        Spacer()
        Sonar()
        Spacer()
        NavBar()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code of sonar view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Sonar : View {

@State private var sonarAtived: Bool = false

private var animationSonarCircleOne: Animation {
 Animation.basic(duration: 0.2, curve: .easeInOut)
    .delay(0)
}

private var animationSonarCircleTwo: Animation {
    Animation.basic(duration: 0.2, curve: .easeInOut)
    .delay(0.1)
}

private var animationSonarCircleThree: Animation {
    Animation.basic(duration: 0.2, curve: .easeInOut)
    .delay(0.25)
}

private var animationButtonSublay: Animation {
    Animation.basic(duration: 0.7, curve: .easeInOut)
    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
}

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 20) {
    ZStack {
        // Button sublay
        Circle()
        .animation(animationButtonSublay)
        .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
        .padding(10)
        .foregroundColor(Color.init(red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, opacity: 0.4))
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.init(red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, opacity: self.sonarAtived ? 0.5 : 0), lineWidth: self.sonarAtived ? 30 : 0))

        // Button
        Button(action: {
        self.sonarAtived.toggle()
        }) {
        Text("Enregistrer ma position")
            .color(.white)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .font(.system(size: 22))
        }
        .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color.init(red: 231/255, green: 76/255, blue: 60/255, opacity: 1.0))
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.init(red: 192/255, green: 57/255, blue: 43/255, opacity: 1.0), lineWidth: 3))
        .clipShape(Circle())

        // Circles
        Circle()
        .animation(animationSonarCircleOne)
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250, alignment: .center)
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.init(red: 52/255, green: 73/255, blue: 94/255, opacity: self.sonarAtived ? 0.18 : 0.0), lineWidth: 1))
        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
        Circle()
        .animation(animationSonarCircleTwo)
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.init(red: 52/255, green: 73/255, blue: 94/255, opacity: self.sonarAtived ? 0.15 : 0.0), lineWidth: 1))
        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
        Circle()
        .animation(animationSonarCircleThree)
        .frame(width: 550, height: 600, alignment: .center)
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.init(red: 52/255, green: 73/255, blue: 94/255, opacity: self.sonarAtived ? 0.10 : 0.0), lineWidth: 1))
        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code of menu view, unwanted exceed:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavBar : View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
    Image("navigation_border")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    HStack {

        Spacer()

        // Compass button
        Button(action: {
        // Code here
        }) {
        Image("ic_compass")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(40), alignment: .center)
        Text("Boussole")
            .color(Color(red: 52/255, green: 73/255, blue: 94/255, opacity: 0.4))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
        }.frame(height: CGFloat(50), alignment: .bottomLeading)

        Spacer()

        // Travel button
        Button(action: {
        // Code here
        }) {
        Image("ic_travel")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(40), alignment: .center)
        Text("Parcours")
            .color(Color(red: 52/255, green: 73/255, blue: 94/255, opacity: 0.4))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
        }.frame(height: CGFloat(50), alignment: .bottomLeading)

        Spacer()

        // Settings button
        PresentationLink(destination: Settings()) {
        Image("ic_settings")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
        Text("Paramètres")
            .color(Color(red: 52/255, green: 73/255, blue: 94/255, opacity: 0.4))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
        }.frame(height: 50, alignment: .bottomLeading)

        Spacer()

    }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70, alignment: Alignment.center)
    }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 90, maxHeight: 90, alignment: Alignment.center)
  }
}
```